# What is the conflict in this yacc parser?

Tags: parsing, yacc

I used the -v option in yacc to produce a y.output file.  At the top of the file it says

State 98 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

Further down in the file is the following:

```
state 98

   30 selection_stmt: IF '(' expression ')' statement .
   31               | IF '(' expression ')' statement . ELSE statement

    ELSE  shift, and go to state 101

    ELSE      [reduce using rule 30 (selection_stmt)]
    $default  reduce using rule 30 (selection_stmt)
```

What is the conflict, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find shift/reduce conflict in this yacc file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737460/how-to-find-shift-reduce-conflict-in-this-yacc-file)

Answer (score 1):

Just about *every* shift/reduce error with `if/then/else` statement is the infamous [dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.

With this code segment:

```
if (f1):
    if (f2):
        c1
    else:
        c2
```

*you* (and Python due to it's bizarre indentation rules) know which `if` the `else` belongs to, but a parser is not so clever.

It can't tell whether the `else` belongs to the first or second `if`.

[This link](http://www.cs.manchester.ac.uk/~pjj/complang/g2lr.html#5) shows how to convert the LR(n) to an LR(1) equivalent which should solve the problem.

Another alternative is to change your base language definition (if possible) so that the ambiguity disappears:

```
: IF '(' cond ')' THEN statement ENDIF
| IF '(' cond ')' THEN statement ELSE statement ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
election_stmt: IF '(' expression ')' statement . selection_stmt_else_part;
selection_stmt_else_part: ELSE statement 
                        | 
                        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahem, the correct answer to this problem is usually: ***do nothing***.

Shift/reduce conflicts are *expected* with ambiguous grammars. They are not *errors*, they are *conflicts*.

The conflict will be resolved by preferring shift over reduce, which just happens to solve the canonical dangling else problem.

And bison even has an %expect *n* statement so that you don't get a S/R conflict warning when there are exactly *n* conflicts.