# YACC: finding shift/reduce conflicts in a grammar

Tags: c, yacc, computation-theory

I am reading the book [theory of computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471095850) and there is a language PL in chapter 2 that is implemented in YACC. The program is very basic. There are grammar rules that are specified, and after running the program, it checks if a given file has the syntax of the specified grammar or not. All the rules are given in the book, and I wanted to implement it.

But when I implemented it, i get the shift/reduce conflict code. I searched the error on the web, and found out that the error refers to grammar ambiguity. I tried finding it but wasn't able to. [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737460/how-to-find-shift-reduce-conflict-in-this-yacc-file) there is a similar question, and a user have pointed out that its a warning and can be ignored since some languages are ambiguous.

Problem:

- Can someone point out where the ambiguity might be?
- When i try to run a code such as following, the program doesn't understand it. it gives syntax error. Although This should be accepted based on the grammar rules that I have applied. Am I passing a grammar with wrong syntax?

  ```
  while X = 10;
  X = Y + 10;
  end;
  ```

My code:

```
    %start program
    %%
    LETTER : 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I'
          | 'J' | 'K' | 'L' | 'M' | 'N' | 'O' | 'P' | 'Q' | 'R'
          | 'S' | 'T' | 'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' | 'Y' | 'Z' 
          ;

    DIGIT : '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
         ;

    name : LETTER
         | name DIGIT
         | name LETTER
         ;


    numeral :   DIGIT 
        |   numeral DIGIT
        ;


    operation   :   '+'
                |   '-'
                |   '*'
                |   '/'
                |   '='
                |   '<'
                |   '>'
                |   '>' '='
                |   '<' '='
                ;

    expression  :   name 
            |   numeral
            |   '(' '!' expression ')'
            |   '(' expression operation expression ')'
            ;

    assignment : name '<' '-' expression
               ;

    instruction : assignment
                | 'g' 'o' 't' 'o' name
                | 's' 't' 'o' 'p'
                ;


    labelinstr : name ':' instruction ';'
               | instruction ';'
               ;

    loop : 'l' 'o' 'o' 'p' expression ';'
         |  name ':' 'l' 'o' 'o' 'p' expression ';'
         ;

    ifthen  :   'i' 'f' expression 't' 'h' 'e' 'n' ';'
            |   name ':' 'i' 'f' expression 't' 'h' 'e' 'n' ';'
            ;
    while   :   'w' 'h' 'i' 'l' 'e' ';'
            |   name ':' 'w' 'h' 'i' 'l' 'e' expression ';'
            ;


    end : 'e' 'n' 'd' ';'
        | name ':' 'e' 'n' 'd' ';'
        ;

    program : labelinstr
            | loop program end
            | while program end
            | ifthen program end
            | ifthen program end 'e' 'l' 's' 'e' ';' program end
            | program program
            ;





    %%
    #include <stdio.h>

    yylex() {
      int c;
      while ( (c=getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
         printf("%c",c);}
      printf("%c",c);
      return(c);
     }
```

Comment: Post the error message. Always.

Comment: There are many problems with this. The most obvious one is that you are not tokenizing your input. You really cannot continue without a separate lexical analysis phase. It makes no sense trying to fix other errors at this point.

Comment: @n.m. I will do lex/yacc later on. But right now I want to simply implement this syntax analyzer with yacc.

Comment: By the way, your sample program is a syntax error because in your language, `X = 10` is not an assignment statement. It is an expression, but expressions are not statements. The assignment statement uses `<-`, so you would need to write `X <- 10`.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread the grammar and thought you have keyword/name conflicts. You don't since they differ in case. Anyway having a separate lexer will simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambiguity problems are not related to your syntax errors. Consider this:

```
 while   :   'w' 'h' 'i' 'l' 'e' ';'
         |   name ':' 'w' 'h' 'i' 'l' 'e' expression ';'
         ;
```

Something is missing in one of the alternatives. You want to loop while something when labeled, and while nothing when unlabeled?

```
 while   :   'w' 'h' 'i' 'l' 'e' expression ';'
         |   name ':' 'w' 'h' 'i' 'l' 'e' expression ';'
         ;
```

Aside: you should really factor out the labels. You already have a "labeled statement" production. Use it.

```
 while X = 10;
```

An expression is either a simple name or number, or parenthesized, so `X = 10` is invalid on its own.

```
 while (X = 10) ;
```

This is not an assignment:

```
 X = Y + 10;
```

This is:

```
 X <- (Y + 10) ;
```

With these fixes there is no longer a syntax error (there are still conflicts but they are unrelated).

Answer (score 3):

The first step in identifying shift/reduce conflicts is to use the `-v` flag to `bison` and examine the state machine in the resulting file which will have the suffice `.output`. That will tell you which states exhibit the error and which rules lead to that state. For example, with your program, we see two states with shift/reduce conflicts, state 65 and state 84.

State 84 is relatively simple:

```
State 84

   72 program: ifthen program end .
   73        | ifthen program end . 'e' 'l' 's' 'e' ';' program end

    'e'  shift, and go to state 101

    'e'       [reduce using rule 72 (program)]
    $default  reduce using rule 72 (program)
```

That is similar to the classic "dangling else" problem. Normally using a statement terminator like `end;` will solve this problem, but the grammar you present curiously insists on having an `end;` even in the case of an `else` clause. So

```
if (a > 3) then a <- 3; else a <- 2; end,
```

is not valid. Instead, the grammar insists on

```
if (a > 3) then a <- 3; end; else a <- 2; end;
```

That doesn't help solve the dangling else problem because the `end` doesn't distinguish between statements with and without `else` clauses, so the following is still ambiguous:

```
if (a > 3) then if (a < 7) then a <- 3; end; else a <- 7; end;
```

It seems to be unlikely that the grammar is correct. I suspect that the `if` productions  should be:

```
        | ifthen program end
        | ifthen program 'e' 'l' 's' 'e' ';' program end
```

The other problem is in state 65: (here, I've omitted the transitions)

```
State 65

   74 program: program . program
   74        | program program .
```

That is clearly ambiguous. Suppose you had:

```
statement statement statement
```

This could be parsed as either binding left-to-right or right-to-left:

```
[program: [program: statement] [program: [program: statement] [program: statement]]] 
[program: [program: [program: statement] [program: statement]] [program: statement]]
```

Roughly speaking the solution is usually something like:

```
statement: if_statement
         | loop_statement
         | ...

program: statement
       | program statement
```

Although personally, I'd probably factor out the labels.

Comment: thank you for response. Can you elaborate what you mean by "factor out the labels".

Comment: @Neo: You have a bunch of productions like `ifthen: blah blah blah | name ':' blah blah blah`; `while: blah blah blah | name ':' blah blah blah`; etc. I would just do: `labeled_statement: statement | name ':' statement; statement: ifthen | while | ...; ifthen: blah blah blah; while: blah blah blah; ...` So the label is factored into a single place rather than being spread all over. ("Refactoring" is the classic way of describing this process, in any computer program.)